# Objects and attribute values

Tags: java

I need help with my homework. Please note that I have finished the code below myself, but am not sure if I am doing it correctly, especially the last sentence of my homework assignment.

My homework assignment:

> Define a class called Building with the following properties. Every Building has a square footage (area) and stories. The constructor creates a Building with these two attributes. The methods get_squarefootage(), get_stories(), set_square_footage(), and set_stories() will be used to get and set the respective attribute values. The method get_info() will return all the current attribute values of the Building. **Write a program that lets a user create Building objects and change their attribute values.**

```
package building_hw2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Building {

    int area;
    int stories;

    int get_squarefootage() { //get values of the area
        return area;
    }

    int get_stories() { //get values of the stories
        return stories;
    }

    void set_square_footage(int area) { //set values of the area
        this.area = area;
    }

    void set_stories(int stories) { //set values of the stories
        this.stories = stories;
    }

    void get_info() { //return all the current attribute balues of the building
        System.out.println("The square footage of the building is " + area);
        System.out.println("The building has " + stories + " stories");
    }

    //main method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Building Bldg = new Building(); //create a building object

    Bldg.area = 40000;
    Bldg.stories = 5;

    Bldg.get_info(); //display the current values of the building

    //get user input to create building object
    Scanner keybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the square footage(area) of the building : ");
    int bldgArea = keybd.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter the stories : ");
    int bldgStories = keybd.nextInt();

    Bldg.set_square_footage(bldgArea);
    Bldg.set_stories(bldgStories);

    Bldg.get_squarefootage();
    Bldg.get_stories();

    Bldg.get_info();
}

}
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Did i write the code according to requirements? Sorry, I know it sounds dumb, but it is what it is :)

Comment: I am not understanding the part where he says "Lets a user create Building Objects"

Comment: You should set your attributes private and your methods public because   it is only accessible in the package

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "pre-grading" a completed homework assignment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be doing it correctly. However I would like to point out a few things. First you should declare the member variables as private for better encapsulation of your class. You already have setter methods for changing the attribute value.

```
int area;
int stories;
```

In your main you can set building values as follows :

```
 Bldg.set_square_footage_area(40000);
 Bldg.set_stories(5);
```

The requirement for get_info is not very clear you should ask what exactly should be returned (some string representation of the attributes or just print current values of all attributes)

Comment: I did ask him the following: Hi Professor,

I want to clarify: 

"The method get_info() will return all the current attribute values of the Building"

- When the program is Run, it should display the current squarefootage and stories of the building to the user (e.g. Currently, the building is 40000 squarefeet and has 8 stories) - is this what you are asking us for? In addition are you also asking us to calculate the total squarefootage of each story in the building?

Comment: If a building has 8 stories, and the total squarefootage is 40000, should the program display that each story is 5000 squarefeet?                           and his response was:            Display the total square footage. That is it.

Comment: in that case you are doing whats required in get_info

Comment: Forgot to mention that he is also asking for a simple interface to get user input. Currently, this is what I display when the program is Run and after the user input..is this correct?       The square footage of the building is 40000
The building has 5 stories
Please enter the square footage(area) of the building : 
500
Please enter the stories : 
5
The square footage of the building is 500
The building has 5 stories

Comment: Looks good to me, however I am unable to understand why are you assigning Bldg.area = 40000;
    Bldg.stories = 5; at the start of main when you are getting input from user

Comment: Isn't he asking "The method get_info() will return all the CURRENT attribute values of the Building.

Comment: @Insane: It's hard to say.. that wouldn't make sense but you could construct a `Building` object containing just those values and then retrieve and print them.. I haven't seen the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing "returning" and "printing to the console". The get_info() method should return something. It shouldn't print anything.

Fields should be private. Methods, in this case, should be public, since you want any other class to be able to call them. And you forgot to provide a constructor, althoughh your teacher asked you to provide one.

Please kindly inform your teacher that naming conventions exist in Java, and that teaching other conventions is not a good idea at all. A whole lot of frameworks and APIs assume the respect of the standard conventions. `get_squarefootage()` should be named `getSquareFootage()`. Same for the setter. Use real words, starting with a lowercase letter, for your variables: `building`, and not `Bldg`.

Comment: And of course [here are the official code conventions from Sun/Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 1):

`get_info` should either return a `String` or be renamed to `printBuildingAttributes`.

You have `Bldg.area`, but why not have a setter method for this field? That would jive with your getter/setter paradigm. It looks like you already have it, so use it. Make the fields themselves private and only accessible thru your getter/setter methods.

If you are going to retrieve the number of stories or area of a building, you need to store it in a variable. Right now, you are retrieving it and throwing it away.

Also, `get_info` or `get_area` is not the right Java convention for method naming.